# JAX-WS return empty element

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I use JAX-WS and it returns list of product's entity.

Product has these attributes:

- id
- name
- description
- etc.

Description have values String or null. I debuged list with products and values of description are valid. When description is null, description element is not included in a SOAP response. I want to have this element in SOAP response with NULL value.

This is dump of response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getProductsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://blabla.com/">
         <return>
            <idProduct>1</idProduct>
            <name>name</name>
            <description>some desc</description>
         </return>
         <return>
            <idProduct>2</idProduct>
            <name>name</name>
         </return>
      </ns2:getProductsResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I want:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getProductsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://blabla.com/">
         <return>
            <idProduct>1</idProduct>
            <name>name</name>
            <description>some desc</description>
         </return>
         <return>
            <idProduct>2</idProduct>
            <name>name</name>
            <description>NULL</description>
         </return>
      </ns2:getProductsResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

This is my web method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getProducts")
public List<ProductDTO> getProducts(@WebParam(name = "idCompany") int idCompany) {
        ProductHelper helper = new ProductHelper();
        // this list was debuged and it is correct
        List<ProductDTO> products = helper.getAll(idCompany);
        return products;
}
```

I use JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-740

Comment: Well, you could iterate over the list of POJOs and set the values to `"NULL"` whenever they are `null` before marshaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the computer can't tell that you want a `null` to be serialized as the string “`NULL`”; this is not at all obvious to computers. (It also won't be obvious to your clients.) So instead the computer handles the `null` in the default JAXB way: it omits the element.

If you want the element to be there, you need to use a JAXB annotation on the `ProductDTO` to say that that is the case. You probably also want to make the element nullable; while it won't be converted to exactly what you say you're looking for, it should at least do the right thing (and your clients ought to be able to cope).

That would be putting an annotation like this on the `description` field (or `getDescription()` method):

```
@XmlElement(required=true, nillable=true)
```

---

The other way of doing this is to add a `getDescription()` method that returns the string `"NULL"` when it would otherwise return a `null` (and the real value otherwise). The problem with that is that it might confuse your database binding layer; doing the job properly by annotating the element sensibly (and using a better serialization) leads to far less pain.

Comment: Theoretically, you might be using something other than JAXB for the XML serialization engine. If so, I can't help…

Comment: Thank you, I absolutely forgot on the annotations. It is the correct way! NULL value is not required, required is description element in soap response, because it missed. And it was a source of exceptions.